# Parsing between two drop down lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract data from a website using Selenium and Python, this site has two drop down menus.
The site is about toll prices, the first drop-down menu has the categories (Auto, Bus, Truck, etc.) the second menu is the toll.
So far I can extract the data specifying in the code the options of the tolls one by one, I would like to know if there is a way to select them by means of a for loop or something.
that the toll changes to the next option when it has already extracted all the options from the first menu, for example, if I have selected the toll 1, all the existing categories for that toll are extracted, once that has been done, it changes to Toll 2, and so on until all the information can be extracted.
Here is the code that I have so far:

```
`from datetime import date
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Get the current date
today = str(date.today())

# Here you save the Path were is the driver
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

# You tell to selenium where is the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# Open the website
driver.get('http://www.triunfoconcebra.com.br/home')
#scroll down untill you can see the table
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="tarifas txt-center"]')
table.location_once_scrolled_into_view

# create all the list that we are going to use
vehicle = list()
tollName = list()
ax = list()
rodamento = list()
pr = list()
# here we select the part of the page with which we are going to manipulate (This will be deleted if 
the for loop works)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphContent_ddlTipoTarifa'))
# here we save all the option from the drop down list available, in this case for the vehicle type
type = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="ctl00$cphContent$ddlTipoTarifa"]/option')
for q in type:
    vehicle.append(q.text)
#print("carros",vehicle)
#Toll names
toll = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="ctl00$cphContent$ddlPracas"]/option')
for t in toll:
    tollName.append(t.text)
#print("casetas",tollName)
# Here we are locate where are the options from the drop down menu
sel = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cphContent_ddlPracas'))
    # This is for Toll 1
select.select_by_visible_text('Automóvel')
sel.select_by_visible_text('P1 - Alexânia')
ax.append(tollName[0])
ax.append(vehicle[0])
pr.append(tollName[0])
pr.append(vehicle[0])
# Here are the axle and vehicle type information
axles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="left eixo bg-branco" or @ class="left eixo bg- 
cinza"]')
#Here are the prices information
prices = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="left valor bg-branco" or @ class="left valor 
bg-cinza"]')
# get the prices and the vehicle type from the table

for i in axles:
    axle = i.find_element_by_xpath('./span')
    ax.append(axle.text)
for a in prices:
    pr.append(a.text)

#Close the website
driver.quit()
`
```

Comment: What about the code you have written isn't working properly? Can you add more detail?

Comment: Hi,The code is working but, to extract the information of the next toll, I must write or copy again all the lines from the comment that says This is for toll 1, and manually write the next toll option, what I want to know is if it is You can change this automatically maybe with a for loop, so that once you extract the information for all car categories from the for the first toll, it will automatically change the option to the second toll and extract the information from the categories available for the toll now selected.

Comment: A for loop sounds like a good idea. If you run into trouble writing that you can update your question with the problem you encounter. You should attempt to write it yourself first, and if you have trouble you can ask for help